# How to crop an image with a transparent hole into a circle without losing transparency?

Tags: php, gd

I have an image which has a transparent hole in the middle. I want to first resize the image and then rotate it. I already achieved this.

Now, I want to crop this image into a circle. I am unable to do this, without losing the transparency of the hole in the middle.

At this moment I generated this image with a script:

[image: this image]

How can I make the corners transparent without losing transparency of the hole?

I have used [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953262/transparent-circle-cropped-image-with-php). However, the hole is not transparent anymore.

Comment: Can you rotate then apply the transparency/transparencies?

Comment: yes, i did that. First I modify the image and then i want to crop the image into a circle wouthout losing transparency of the whole image. However I lose the transparency of the whole.

Comment: I found a solution. I created an overlay and merged it with my orginal image. Then I made the corners transparent with imagefill.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created an overlay and merged it with my orginal image. Then I made the corners transparent with imagefill.